# Use MSVC linker with link script

Tags: c, linker, ld

There is `ld` on linux to link files, which can be used in a link script.
But if on windows? 
When I use `ld` in mingw on windows to link some `.o` files with the same script on linux, it has failed.

It says

> cannot perform PE operations on non PE output file

I just want to locate the address at the program's begin as 
`0xffff800000000000`.

So I think there is a way to write a link script for MSVC to link my program `addreaa` on a right address to execute.
If so, are there any docs about how to write this kind of script?
If not, how can I realize this purpose?
THANKS